# Describe each of the following sets interval notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

a) $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) $

b) $  \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$

c) $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n}, 2+\frac{1}{n})$

Could anyone please explain how to do this problems? I'm having a hard time trying to come up with the intervals for these sets; and the book doesn't contain anything like it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sets in (a) and (b) are intersections: a real number $x$ is in one of those sets if and only if it’s in every one of the sets being intersected. Let’s look at (a): when is a real number $x$ in the interval $\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$? This happens exactly when $-\frac1n<x<\frac1n$. If $x>0$, we can always fine an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<x$, and then $x\notin\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$. I’ll leave it to you to show similarly that if $x<0$, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\notin\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$. On the other hand, $-\frac1n<0<\frac1n$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $0\in\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$. Thus, the only real number in the intersection is $0$, and the intersection is therefore $\{0\}$. How can we express that as an interval? Remember that $[a,b]=\{x:a\le x\le b\}$, so $[0,0]=\{x:0\le x\le 0\}=\{0\}$: it’s the degenerate closed interval $[0,0]$.

You can work (b) similarly, and in that one you won’t have to worry about a degenerate interval.

In (c) you have to deal with a union: $x\in\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\left(-\frac1n,2+\frac1n\right)$ if and only if there is at least one $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\in\left(-\frac1n,2+\frac1n\right)$. Notice that

$$\left(-\frac1{n+1},2+\frac1{n+1}\right)\subseteq\left(-\frac1n,2+\frac1n\right)\;,$$

so that the intervals are getting smaller as $n$ gets bigger. That means that every one of them is a subset of the first, biggest interval, and that fact should make it very easy to see what the union is.

Comment: Brian, could you elaborate a little more on problems B and C. I know the answers but I just don't understand how my professor got them. Is there some kind of strategy that will make it easier to see what the interval is?

Comment: @Kururugi: All three of these problems are made easier by the fact that the intervals in the intersections and the union are nested: if $I_n$ is the $n$-th interval, then in all three problems we have $I_1\supsetneqq I_2\subsetneqq I_3\ldots$. In (b) you already know from (a) that the lefthand endpoints $-\frac1n$ are squeezing up to $0$: if $x<0$, then $x\notin I_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, so $x$ can’t be in the intersection. On the other hand, $0$ clearly is in all of the intervals and hence in the intersection, so the intersection must be an interval whose lefthand end is $[0$. ...

Comment: ... On the right you can reason similarly to see that the righthand endpoints of the intervals $I_n$ are squeezing down to $1$: if $x>1$, you can find an $n$ big enough so that $x\notin I_n$. On the other hand, $1\in I_n$ for every $n$, so $1$ is in the intersection. It’s clear that everything between $0$ and $1$ is also in all of the $I_n$, so the intersection must be $[0,1]$: we’ve excluded everything else. In (c) the nesting means that $I_n\subseteq I_1$ for every $n$. Thus, the union of these intervals is simply $I_1$, the largest: if $x\in I_n$ for some $n$, then $x\in I_1$. Thus, the ...

Comment: ... other intervals are actually redundant in the union, just as $(1,2)$ is redundant in the union $(0,2)\cup(1,2)$.

Comment: Now I think I get it. However, for B would the answer exclude zero and meaning (0,1] and include 1 since the summation of $1 + 1/n$ will get to the point where you will only have 1.. then $x \geq 1$?

Comment: @Kururugi: No, the intersection in (b) will include $0$: $0\in\left(-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right)$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $0$ is in the intersection of these intervals. You get $0$ at the lefthand end for exactly the same reason that you get $1$ on the righthand end: no interval excludes it. But anything less than $0$ or strictly greater than $1$ is excluded by some interval and is therefore not in the intersection.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and Thanks for the explanation, I think I get it now.

Comment: @Kururugi: No problem; you’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For part $(a)$, the claim is $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) = \{0\}$. To see this you have to show $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq \{0\}  $ and $ \{0\} \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})  $.  The second inclusion is eay since $0$ lies is all the intervals. For the second first inclusion, pick a point $x$ in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) $, and explain why this point must be zero.